# ¿Cómo agregar foreach dentro de tabla dinámica con javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-8

Tengo una tabla dinámica con javascript pero ocupo mostrar un select dinámico para que puedan buscar usuarios, anteriormente lo intente con select2 de jquery pero al no funcionarme estoy optando por meter un select dinámico normal, solo que no se como acomodar mi foreach dentro de la tabla dinamica o si mi sintaxis esta incorrecta, agradeceria la ayuda, y aqui esta mi codigo javascript con el foreach:

```js
< script >
  function agregar() {
    cont++;
    con2++;
    con3++;
    con4++;
    con5++;
    con6++;
    con7++;

    var fila = ' <tr id="' + cont + '"><th scope="row"><input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha' + con2 + '"></th><td><select class="form-control col-md-12" name="users_id" id="users_id' + con3 + '"><?php @foreach($user as $u)' < option value = "'{{ $u->id }}'" > {
      {
        $u - > name
      }
    } {
      {
        $u - > ap1
      }
    } {
      {
        $u - > ap2
      }
    } < /option>' @endforeach ?></select > < /td><td><input type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad'+con4+'"></td > < td > < select class = "form-control"
    name = "producto_id"
    id = "producto_id'+con5+'" > < /select></td > < td > < input type = "text"
    name = "descripcion"
    id = "descripcion'+con6+'" > < /td><td><input type="file" name="file" id="file'+con7+'" accept="image/ * "><br></td></tr>';

    // Volver a renderizar el control desplegable
    $('#dataTable > tbody:last-child').append(fila);

  } <
  /script>
```

Y los datos los mando llamar desde el controlador:

$user = User::all();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que `$u->name, $u->ap1 y $u->ap2` no te dan problemas, el código correcto para el select sería el siguiente:

```
<select>
@foreach($user as $u)
@php 
    $opt = $u->name . '' . $u->ap1 . '' . $u->ap2;
@endphp
    <option value = "{{ $u->id }}" > {{ $opt }} </option> 
@endforeach 
</select >
```

Al estar utilizando un .blade.php no es necesario que abras `<?php` para poder utilizar el `@foreach` o cualquier otro elemento válido que empiece por `@`.
Dentro del `foreach` he creado una variable en php llamada `$opt` que almacena lo que quieras pintar.
Luego escribo naturalmente la `<option...>` y dentro de ella imprimo el valor usando `{{ $opt }}`.

Te recomiendo que revises https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Olvidé copiar los atributos que tenías en el `select` el `name`, el `id` y demás, no te olvides de añadirlos de nuevo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, probé tal como me dijiste y funciono